# Getting all indexes of elements fulfilling a certain condition using Underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I want to retrieve all the indexes of the elements in an Array which fulfills a certain condition. For ex if I have an array like:

```
var countries = ["India", "Australia", "United States", "Brazil"];
```

And I would want to get the indexes of those elements whose string length is more than 5, I should get back an array like

```
[2, 3]
```

Or even an object like :

```
{
  2: "United States",
  3: "Australia"
}
```

Is there any inbuilt/native function in JavaScript or underscore.js that I can leverage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vanilla JS, to get the indexes:

```
var longnames = ["India", "Australia", "United States", "Brazil"]
  .map( function( item, idx ){
    // convert the names to indexes if name is linger than 5 characters
    return ( item.length > 5) ? idx : null
  }).filter(function(item){
    // fiter out the nulls
    return item;
  });
  // returns [1,2,3] since "Australia".length > 5
```

Since underscore has both `.map` and `.reduce` methods you should be able "underscorize" this solution ;)

To create an object in the form `{ index : name }`:

```
var longnames = ["India", "Australia", "United States", "Brazil"]
  .reduce( function( ret, name, idx ){
    if( name.length > 5 ){
      ret[ idx ] = name;
    }
    return ret;
  }, {});

  /* returns 
    Object { 1: "Australia", 2: "United States", 3: "Brazil" }
   */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spht39wc/

Alternative .reduce using underscore:

```
 var longnames = _.reduce(["India", "Australia", "United States", "Brazil"], 
  function( ret, name, idx ){
    if( name.length > 5 ){
      ret[ idx ] = name;
    }
    return ret;
  }, {});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49vc82n7/

Comment: Thanks ... this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this (pure JavaScript):

```
var countries = ["India", "Australia", "United States", "Brazil"];
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++)
{
  if(countries[i].length > 5) {
    result.push(i);
    console.log(countries[i]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvw4zvff/2/)

OR same with jQuery:

```
var sum=[];
$.each( ["India", "Australia", "United States", "Brazil"], function(   index, value ){
value.length > 5 && sum.push(value);
});

console.log(sum);
```

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7404/)